# is datastore only possible database option if you host app with gae?

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

wont gae allow connecting to mysql even external mysql on other server? I am new in gae and seemed to me you have no way but using datasrore.

Comment: You haven't read googles docs,  look up cloud sql

Answer (score 0):

GAE provides two internal [persistent structured storage service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/): datastore and Cloud SQL.

You *could* use an external data storage service, but the limitation of GAE is that it can only make HTTP requests to external services, so

There is an option of using outgoing sockets, but in practice this is quite limited and I haven't yet seen a working jdbc implementation using it. Also, you will not be able to do persistent jdbc connections as the lifetime of request on GAE is limited to 30 seconds.

Comment: thank u for ur answer. firstly i dont know about jdbc. what i need is mysql and app i use is python or php not java. so if I set hostname in my python or php application : mysql-something.hostname.com and password and database name and then try to connect to that external mysql database on that host would it be http request? if yes why should it be quite limited in practice?

Comment: No, database connections are usually persistent (=long-running) socket connections, not HTTP connections.

Comment: Your best option would be to look at Cloud SLQ, which is a google-hosted mysql service: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/